# How to remove cirlce,line,square symbol from highchart

Tags: highcharts

Here i have my highchart display image 
[image]

and i have tried to remove top right corner symbols(text,square,line,circle)
[image]

but didn't find option to remove those (text,square,line,circle) symbols.

Comment: updated your post with the code how you are getting symbols. Update previous demo https://jsfiddle.net/m9u8f6ur/

Comment: same codes are  use in my project @deep-3015, the symbols not there in fiddle but didn't kow how they generated in my project.

Comment: am used Highstock JS v2.1.9 (2015-10-07)

Comment: is there any way to disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use our plugin for Highcharts: [Annotations](https://github.com/blacklabel/annotations). Simply set:

```
annotationsOptions: {
  enabledButtons: false
}
```

Docs: https://github.com/blacklabel/annotations#chartannotationsoptions

**Note:
Plugin is deprecated, we suggest to use [official Annotations plugin](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module).**